# GoDaddy Intermediate certificate for Apache 2.2.31 / Amazon Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy

I bought an SSL certificate for my domain from GoDaddy.

The following are the contents:

1. The certificate file
2. `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`

I have vhost on my `Apache 2.2.31` web server. The following is the configuration (`httpd.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile [[path_to_certificate]]
        SSLCertificateKeyFile [[path_to_key]]
        SSLCertificateChainFile [[path_to_gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt]]
        ServerName [[domain_nme]]
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

Its working properly in Google Chrome. In Andriod clients, an `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException` is thrown. It is because of a bad intermediate certificate.

Question:

1. Is the file `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` that comes with the download the correct one?
2. If yes, what is the problem with my configuration?

Note: The SSL test at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html also says the chain is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the `gdig2.crt` listed at the [GoDaddy Certificate Repository](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository#). It should have also been included in the bundle you downloaded.

Once you have that, and know the root certificate, you can verify it with:

`openssl verify -verbose -CAfile <(cat gdroot-g2.crt gdig2.crt) yourcert.crt`

If it is ok you should see something like `<certname>:OK`

Once you've made sure that all works, then you can retry your SSLLabs test.

Hope that helps. =)